# Dynamically adding menu items randomly disappear in ASP .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a header control which is included in every page.
I create dynamic menu in Header control based on user rights and modules provided.

Menu is created in following string format.

**Code Behind**

`

```
string dynamicMenu =
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='/User/HomePage' runat='server' id='HOME'>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='/User/Files' runat='server' id='MyFiles'>My Files</a>
    </li>
</ul>;
divMenu.InnerHtml = dynamicMenu;
```

`

**ASPX**

`<div id="divMenu" runat="server"></div>`

Problem is that, some times menu disappears and rendered menu div has only `<ul/>` tag and l
looks like

`<div id="divMenu" runat="server"> <ul/> </div>`

How can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `<div id="divMenu" runat="server"></div>` with panel in your aspx

in code behind

```
string dynamicMenu = "<ul><li><a href='/User/HomePage' runat='server' id='HOME'>Home</a></li><li><a href='/User/Files' runat='server' id='MyFiles'>My Files</a></li></ul>";
Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(dynamicMenu));
```

Comment: I am trying this, but I want to know why panel will work and div will not?

Comment: I doubt that you didn't put double quotes around the string. and i think you are using jquery or javascript. div can't access like you did in server side